# Convert column resultset to row SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to StackOverflow and this is my first post.

Here is what I want to achieve, 
I want to print all the names where id = 1 in a single row

Here is a result I want to achieve  for Id = 1 query

Id Names
1  Tom Smith, Paul Walker, Peter Robin

Here is the sample table

```
CREATE TABLE myData(
ID INT NOT null, 
FirstName NVARCHAR(20),
LastName NVARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO myData
VALUES(1,'Tom','Smith')
INSERT INTO myData
VALUES(2,'Jared','Williams')
INSERT INTO myData
VALUES(1,'Paul','Walker')
INSERT INTO myData
VALUES(4,'Mary','Elisabeth')
INSERT INTO myData
VALUES(1,'Peter','Robin')
INSERT INTO myData
VALUES(2,'Chen','Leo')
```

Comment: Do you know how many there will be (a max number of records returned)?  You need to look into PIVOT.  Most likely dynamic PIVOT based off the answer to the number of possible records returned. Also question is why do you need it this way?

Comment: This isn't a PIVOT, this is a GROUP CONCAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `string_agg` with `group by`

```
select id, string_agg(Concat(FirstName, ' ', LastName),',')
from myData
group by id
```

For old versions of Sql Server

```
SELECT ID,  result = STUFF(
   (SELECT ',' + Concat(FirstName, ' ', LastName)
    FROM myData t1
    WHERE t1.id = t2.id
    FOR XML PATH (''))
   , 1, 1, '') from myData t2
group by id;
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in the post.  I'm using SQL Server 2012 and it does not have built-in string_agg  Function

Comment: please check my answer again

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot